# Play an audible when a uniquely named window appears

Tags: windows, audio, triggers

I'd like to know if it's possible to trigger an audible alert when a Windows window with a unique Title appears on one of three monitors.  Yes, the window appears, but it may be occluded by a different application.  The audible would be an indicator to go look for it.